# Is it possible to reverse alias a c# namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Not sure how to phrase this question, but here is the problem.

I have a namespace designed: `my.foo.bar`

In one of my classes, I accidentally named the namespace `my.foo.Bar`

I want to fix the namespace capitalization so that everyone is on the same page, but this is a shared library, and I can't afford to recompile all programs using this.

So, is there something I can create that, in essence, redirects `my.foo.Bar` to `my.foo.bar`?

Comment: Use VB.NET to access your library -- it's case-insensitive. ;-) (ok, just kidding)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not globally.  You can use [namespace aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?ppud=4), but only in the client code.  It sounds like you might need to take a breaking change.

One way of doing it, if it is only one or two classes, would be to copy them from `my.foo.Bar` to `my.foo.bar`, deprecate the ones in the bad namespace using the [Obsolete attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.obsoleteattribute.aspx), and slowly move clients over to the correct ones.

If the class is stateless, then the class in the `my.foo.Bar` namespace could delegate to the one in the `my.foo.bar` namespace as @JohnSaunders suggests, but only if client's usage of that class doesn't preclude delegation (everything is a method or a property, that class's Type isn't used via reflection, etc).

Comment: In this case, it's a small class, 4 properties and 3 overloaded constructors.

Answer (score 6):

The best you can do is to take all of the types in the badly-named namespace, and create versions of them in the correct namespace. These can delegate to the bad namespace versions.

Comment: Perhaps `using myBar = my.foo.Bar`. The constraint 'unmodifiable shared library' greatly restricts the options.

Comment: @John How would I do that? Inherit from the class in the badly-named namespace? Is that good enough?

Comment: I use ReSharper, so I would simply tell it to create delegating members.